# Suds Error while resolving schema

Tags: python, suds

I am getting the following error at the mentioned line,i enabled debug logging but lost as to how to proceed further?can anyprovide pointers on how to debug this and fix the issue?

CODE:-

```
   request = self.search_soapclient.factory.create('ns0:SearchRequest')
```

ERROR:-

```
DEBUG:suds.resolver:searching schema for (ns0:SearchRequest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local/mnt/workspace/Automation/script.py", line 1659, in <module>

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.6

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.6
    CRInfo = tool.searchforInfo(data)
  File "/local/mnt/workspace/Automation/script.py", line 694, in searchIncompleteInfo
    request = self.search_soapclient.factory.create('ns0:SearchRequest')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 216, in create
    type = self.resolver.find(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/resolver.py", line 108, in find
    result = self.root(parts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/resolver.py", line 130, in root
    qref = self.qualify(parts[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/resolver.py", line 193, in qualify
    return qualify(name, self.wsdl.root, self.wsdl.tns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/__init__.py", line 46, in qualify
    raise Exception('prefix (%s) not resolved' % p)
Exception: prefix (ns0) not resolved
```